# Non-existent class: Mongo_db

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, ion-auth

I have a problem with ion_auth . I converted all required file fit for Mongodb.
my config liles
mongo_db.php

```
<?
   $config['mongo_host'] = 'localhost';
   $config['mongo_port'] = 27017;
   $config['mongo_db'] = 'tls_saas';
   $config['mongo_user'] = 'root';
   $config['mongo_pass'] = 'root';
   $config['mongo_persist'] = TRUE;
   $config['mongo_persist_key'] = 'ci_mongo_persist';
   ?>
```

ion_auth.php

```
$config['use_mongodb'] = TRUE;

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| MongoDB Collection.
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Setup the mongodb docs using the following command:
| $ mongorestore sql/mongo
|
*/
$mongorestore                    = 'sql/mongo';
$config['collections']['users']          = 'users';
$config['collections']['groups']         = 'groups';
$config['collections']['login_attempts'] = 'login_attempts';
```

but still i get the error

> Non-existent class: Mongo_db

is their to make any more changes . ion_auth working with mongodb now ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED !!**
Problem was with code igniter class declaration in LOADER.php .
Add the following lines if you get this error. Code igniter does not allow pages to be loaded if

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

is not found at the beginning of the file then Code igniter skip that file .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and load the library in addition to the config files.

https://github.com/huglester/MongoDB-CodeIgniter-Driver/blob/master/libraries/Mongo_db.php

https://github.com/huglester/MongoDB-CodeIgniter-Driver/blob/master/README

That error indicates you have not added or loaded the library.

Comment: Sir I have included these files in specified parts of codeigniter but still i get same error.
If i load it in autoload i still get same error. It occurs after loading session.php of codeigniter system..

Answer (score 0):

the 'Mongo_db' library which is located in system/libraries/Mongo_db.php ,please edit this file and modify the class name from 'Mongo_db' to 'CI_Mongo_db' that will fixed this issue.